# Prove $f(x)=x$ for every $x \in \mathbb Q_{>0}$.

Tags: calculus

Let $\mathbb Q_{>0}$ be the set of all positive rational numbers. Let $f:\mathbb Q_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a function that complies:

1) For every $x,y \in \mathbb Q_{>0}$, $f(x)f(y)\geq f(xy)$

2) For every $x,y \in \mathbb Q_{>0}$, $f(x+y)\geq f(x)+f(y)$

3) There is a rational number $a$>1 so that $f(a)=a$

Prove $f(x)=x$ for every $x \in \mathbb Q_{>0}$.

Comment: Should the contest-math tag be added, along with a reference to the question?

Answer (score 3):

It is the 5th problem of this year's IMO. Many solutions can be found here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3154373&sid=2f078d2cf711eae22505f3a1aff5ef15#p3154373 (some of them seem to be wrong)

Comment: Assume $f(m)>m$ for any integer $m$, then $f(mn) \ge n\cdot f(m)$ , so for some $N$, we have for $n>N$ that  $f(nm) >nm+m$. Can you please explain me that part? He didn't even use the $N$ in the second equation and in the first one he turned an strict inequality into a not strict one.